# Code does not run in Promise.then for the line of code after the return statement

Tags: javascript, promise, return

I'm trying to setup a timed changing background color function using the promise object. eg:

```
const colorChange = (color, delay) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
            resolve();
        }, delay)
    })
};

colorChange("red", 1000)
    .then(() => {
        return colorChange("blue", 1000);
        console.log("blue");
    })
    .then(() => {
        colorChange("yellow", 1000);
        console.log("yellow");
    })
```

Why does the `console.log("blue")` statement not work when I put return infront of `colorChange("blue",1000);`

does `.then` method only take 1 line of code after return statement?

(I understand you need return for .then to work, I just don't know why the console.log("blue") wouldn't run)

Comment: `return` immediately finishes the function. No code after `return` will be processed. Nothing to do with promises, everything to do with how functions have always worked in JS.

Answer (score 3):

`return` statement ends function execution. So the code after `return` is unreachable. Put `console.log("blue")` before `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Not in JS, in every program language, any code after return statement will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the code, try this code @zzh315

```
const colorChange = (color, delay) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
};

colorChange("red", 1000)
  .then(() => {
    return colorChange("blue", 1000);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("blue");
    return colorChange("yellow", 1000);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("yellow");
  });
```